# TCP server for gps tracker for android app and HTTP server for website and web services

Tags: android, tcp, server, gps, httpserver

I am developing an **android app which is associated with a website** so I need a server for website and for web services. I know that the http is application layer protocol that transfer data through either TCP or UDP.

1. My android app has provision for Google Map for assest tracking.
2. My GPS tracker (tk-102) sends TCP data (I assume it is raw data without application layer protocol).

[image]

Since I will be using a http server for website so **can that server accepts raw data (where it is accepting HTTP data) at TCP socket** and manipulate it?

if yes then how and do I have any other option for the gps task. 
Please suggest a server where I can do this task. I tried searching the net but did not get suitable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using wireshark first to understand actually how your tracker is sending the information. If you can identify the port at which data is being sent you can use iptables to replicate the data and send it to the location of your choice.

Comment: I just found out that It is not following any protocol in application layer(raw data) So can I process that raw data at my  HTTP server's TCP port?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. The simplest could be to use teeproxy (https://github.com/chrislusf/teeproxy) and run another server which can do whaever you want with the raw tcp packets. Hope that helps

Comment: thank you Tapan Chugh. it is working. But is it possible to do the same task using the same server(HTTP), I may use it for commercial purpose and in that case it wont be financially feasible to have 2 servers.

Comment: Not really. The network packets are received by the kernel in a buffer before being received by the server application. There are ways to read these packets from the buffer (used by the likes of wireshark and tcpdump). However, it is not really possible to modify the packets when they are in the buffer. 
You don't need to have 2 servers for this to work, you can run both the server applications on the same server. If you are worried about the performance then you can look at using IPTables for Port Mirroring